# Use undefined constants on purpose

Tags: php, css, oop

So I have a project called **WingStyle**: https://github.com/IngwiePhoenix/WingStyle
It is yet in development, and i need something to make it a little smarter.

In a way I want to get away from some quotes - take "html" as example. When the user calls a function which isn't there yet, the framework auto-loads the class for that purpose and then runs the function. In the process of auto-loading, there is a `__construct` method being triggered.

Let's take the function **`color`** as example. In the normal case, a user would call it like this:

```
<?=WS(...)
    ->color("white")
->end?>
```

But as you may know, we have a set of default colors - white, black, red, orange, etc, etc. Now the problem is that when I try to use the above code WITHOUT quotes, I get the typical `"use of undefined constant"` error. That is why I coded in a loader function which only triggers the initializing code which then adds the constants needed.

As far as I know, the interpreter sees the undefined constant before executing the code - so of course, I can't trigger the initializing code before the constant comes in...

Is there a way in which I can make the interpreter first trigger the initializing code and THEN see the constant? I don't mind sticking with my load-method really, but it just gets annoying adding things to it. I would really like to know of a way in which I could add the constants on the fly.

Check out the projects source to see what I mean.

The functions and mechanisms in questions are found in:

```
classes/WingStyleBase.php:
  - addDefs()
classes/WingStyleManager.php
  - __get()
```

Comment: Just write sensible code in the first place.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point of this library when there are already CSS preprocessors out there such as SASS or LESS?

Comment: Sounds like you really need to create your own language and parser instead of abusing PHP syntax.

Comment: @Mahn: Its not like SASS or LESS. Can one of these two turn one css rule into a multi-browser rule, like the linear-gradient thing which is different in every browser? From what I know, they can't. My library just aims to make that kind of things faster and make you type less for the same code.

Comment: Yes, they can. SASS has macros for gradients etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to add dynamic constants in PHP, though in theory you could write and then import a custom *.php file or something.

Of course, that's breaking what "constant" means.  If it's going to change at run-time, you really want a global variable.

And neither would help you here, since if you or someone else calls `->color(white)` white will be evaluated **BEFORE** it's passed to `color`, in the context of your calling application.  If you want to allow that behavior to happen, just declare a `white` constant early on and use it with wild abandon in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the information, ill stick with the pre-loading then.
But just to add, the constants arent dynamic but are created while the respective classes are important. :)